# Is it normal that tailwind.config.js, vite.config.js are in root folder of Laravel 9?

Tags: tailwind-css, vite, laravel-9

Fresh install of Vite and Tailwind results in `tailwind.config.js`, `postcss.config.js` and `vite.config.js` in the root folder of Laravel 9.

Is this expected? I want to organize these file into the existing `resources/js` folder. Where do I update references to these files to avoid breaking things?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the default behaviour.

You can change the location of your `vite.config.js` to any location you want by using the `--config` flag in your `package.json` script:

```
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite --config custom/location/vite.config.js",
        "build": "vite build --config custom/location/vite.config.js"
    },
```

In the vite.config.js you can change the `tailwind.config.js` and remove the need for your `postcss.config.js` entirely like this:

```
        ...
        css: {
            postcss: {
                plugins: [
                    require("tailwindcss")({
                        config: "custom/location/tailwind.config.js",
                    }),
                    require("autoprefixer"),
                ],
            },
        },
```